# Why can only two electrons occupy a sub-band in carbon nanotubes?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, nanoscience

I understand that only two electrons can occupy an orbital and  Pauli's exclusion principle allows only electrons of opposite spin to occupy any orbital.

Can someone please help me correlate this with the sub-bands?